# How to get reference types base class type

Tags: c#, reference

So I am trying to figure out how to get referenced assemblies base class type.
For example I have the following:

Solution A{

..Project A

....class w

......GetAllClassesSubclassOfClassX() { return constructor if matched }

--Project B

----abstract class x

------abstract methodA()

..Project C

....class y : x

......override methodA()

--Project D

----class z : x

------override methodA()

So my current code pulls back the references but I'm not sure how to see if they are subclasses of a specific class type.

```
public List<AbstractCWThirdPartyConsumer> GetAllProviders()
{
    AssemblyName[] types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies();

    List<AbstractCWThirdPartyConsumer> listOfAllProcessors = new List<AbstractCWThirdPartyConsumer>();
    foreach (AssemblyName type in types)
    {
        if (IsSameOrSubclass(listOfAllProcessors.GetType(), type.GetType()))
        {
             //AbstractCWThirdPartyConsumer proc = (AbstractCWThirdPartyConsumer)type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null);
             //listOfAllProcessors.Add(proc);
        }
    }

        return listOfAllProcessors;
    }

    public bool IsSameOrSubclass(Type potentialBase, Type potentialDescendant)
    {
        return potentialDescendant.IsSubclassOf(potentialBase);
    }
}
```

Any help with correcting my problem would be helpful! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't have abstract projects, nor can projects inherit from each other. I'm assuming `Project A, Project B, ...` are classes?

Comment: What is Solution A? What is Project A, B, ...? How can a project be abstract? What references what? What does pulling back references mean? The type variable is an AssemblyName instance, calling type.GetType() will give you typeof(AssemblyName), what do you want to do with that? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I am sorry. yes Project C and Project D have classes that Reference Project B Class. making the edit now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you use [Type.IsSubclassOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.type.issubclassof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Rewrite your method like this should do.

```
public bool IsSameOrSubclass(Type potentialBase, Type potentialDescendant)
{
    return potentialDescendant.IsSubclassOf(potentialBase);
}
```

Also i do bellieve your approach to enumerate all Types in the assemblies is incorrect so here is a rewritten Version that should fitt your intention:

```
using System.Linq;
...
public List<AbstractCWThirdPartyConsumer> GetAllProviders()
{
    IEnumerable<Assembly> referencedAssemblies = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies().Select(Assembly.Load);

    List<AbstractCWThirdPartyConsumer> listOfAllProcessors = new List<AbstractCWThirdPartyConsumer>();
    foreach (Assembly assembly in referencedAssemblies)
    {
        foreach(Type type in assembly.ExportedTypes)
        {
            if (IsSameOrSubclass(typeof(AbstractCWThirdPartyConsumer), type))
            {
             //AbstractCWThirdPartyConsumer proc = (AbstractCWThirdPartyConsumer)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
             //listOfAllProcessors.Add(proc);
            } 
        }
    }
    return listOfAllProcessors;
}

public bool IsSameOrSubclass(Type potentialBase, Type potentialDescendant)
{
    return potentialDescendant.IsSubclassOf(potentialBase);
}
```

Or if you really want to squeeze it into a single Linq-Method-Chain:

```
public List<AbstractCWThirdPartyConsumer> GetAllProviders()
{
     return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
             .GetReferencedAssemblies()
             .Select(Assembly.Load)
             .SelectMany(asm => asm.ExportedTypes)
             .Where(exportedType => exportedType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AbstractCWThirdPartyConsumer)))
             .Select(exportedType => (AbstractCWThirdPartyConsumer) Activator.CreateInstance(exportedType))
             .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Very nice. But I do see where I was messing up. This helped so much. Thanks! I did have to change ExportedTypes to GetExportedTypes() as im using .Net 3.5 for anyone else that comes across this solution.

Comment: You should note that ExportedTypes means its only public types, incase this makes a difference for you. If this is a problem use GetTypes instead.